# how to obtain the velocity of summitxl?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to know the information of encoder or the velocity of the robot named summitxl. now i just get the information of odom, i don't know how to find the velocity. thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47635/how-to-obtain-the-velocity-of-summitxl?/) by [nicole](https://answers.ros.org/users/3538/nicole/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
Please always add tags when asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What about dividing the distance you get from odom by the elapsed time: v = s/t ? ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity )

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1